# "Controllers as" syntax in $timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pointers, reference

today I'm trying to solve problem with using "controller as" syntax in **$timeout**. I tried to do a "fake pointer", using object. Unluckily it's not working. Have someone an idea how to solve this problem without using **$scope**?

```
this.shakeNotValid = {val: true};

function objChange (obj) {
    console.log(obj.val);
    obj.val = false;
    console.log(obj.val);
}

$timeout(objChange(this.shakeNotValid), 400);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Angular I suggest you to use a variable for the "this", prevents scope errors.

```
var scope = this;
scope.shakeNotValid = {val: true};

function objChange (obj) {
    console.log(obj.val);
    obj.val = false;
    console.log(obj.val);
}

$timeout(function(){objChange(scope.shakeNotValid)}, 400);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your `$timeout`, you forget the anonymous function :

```
var scope = this;
scope.shakeNotValid = {val: true};

$timeout(function() { 
    objChange(scope.shakeNotValid) 
} , 400);
```

The function `$timeout` waits a function in first parameter. `onChange()` (with the bracket) **calls** a function, but it's not a function.

Comment: It's not working. Error "". Current code : this.shakeNotValid = {val: true};

   function objChange (obj) {
       obj.val = false;
   }

   $timeout(function() { 
       objChange(this.shakeNotValid); 
   } , 400);

Comment: @user3452592 catch 'this' into a variable like the answer of kikerrobles

Comment: It's not working. TypeError "Cannot set property 'val' of undefined".  

Current code : 

this.shakeNotValid = {val: true};

function objChange (obj) {
     obj.val = false;
}

$timeout(function() { 
     objChange(this.shakeNotValid); 
} , 400);

In my opinion it's not working because of using "this" in $timeout. Anyway thanks a lot :)